# Computing the entanglement negativity of a sum of eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Is there a way to compute the entanglement negativity of a sum of eigenstates?
Im interested in computing the negativity of
$$
\Xi = \sum_n a_n \rho_n \equiv \sum_n a_n |n\rangle\langle n|,
$$
where $H|n\rangle =E_n |n\rangle$, where $H$ is a free many body Hamiltonian (in my particular case $H$ is a free fermionic Hamiltonian, i.e.$H=\sum_k \epsilon_k d^\dagger_k d_k$ but Im happy with anything similar/else).

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you know the negativities of the $|n\rangle\langle n|$ eigenstates? Otherwise, how does the decomposition help? Of course if you know the negativities of the eigenstates, you can easily upper bound the negativity of the sum by the triangle inequality.

Comment: @user2723984 That’s if $\sum_n |a_n| \leq 1$. I do know the negativity of the individual $|n\rangle \langle n|$ as they are free eigenstates characterised by their correlation matrix. I guess my question is more on the lines *Does anyone know of a way of tackling this problem however unrelated or vague?*

Comment: It's not even obvious that/how negativity makes sense for fermions. Also not that it cannot be simple, since e.g. the maximally mixed states has entangled decompositions, so only an upper bound might be feasible. But you already know that negativity decreases under convex combinations.

Comment: A couple possibly helpful references: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08637, https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09808, https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04211 .

Comment: @NorbertSchuch what about free bosons? Is this calculation possible?

Comment: Free bosons live in an infinite dimensional space ... and they might have convex decompositions which are not free bosons ...